# Query returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, slim

I am trying to query some data from my database. I am trying to do `GET` and put them into array to output it as `JSON`. However it return empty array. My question is why since my database contains information and I know that my connections etc. are correct because I got working `POST`.

I am using **Slim Framework v3** and for connection `PDO`.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$app->get('/users/get', function ($request, $response, $args) {
require 'db.class.php';
$database = new Database();
$database->query("SELECT * FROM `workbungee`.`user`");
$users = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($database)) {

    $users[] = $row;
}
    $struct = array("User" => $users);
    print json_encode($struct);
    return $response->write("Hello " . count($jobArray));

});
```

This is what it returns:

```
{
  "User": []
}
```

In db.class.php I have the following functions:

```
public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

If I try to echo inside while loop, I can't get any output but just status code: 200.

I've tried so many other solutions and have read dozen of questions.

Comment: `$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `workbungee`.`user`");
$users = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
  $users[] = $row;
 }`

Comment: https://arjunphp.com/creating-restful-api-slim-framework/

Comment: In recent years, I've pretty much stopped answering questions on PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. Just sayin'.

Comment: can you try my answer ?

Comment: In a nutshell, this code is extremely inconsistent. You should pay much more attention to the code you are writing.

Comment: @Strawberry, If I understood you correctly, you said that PDO is deprecated and I should use MySQLi?

Comment: no  @Strawberry is saying mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using PDO, not mysql, you have to use PDO methods. One of which is a dedicated method for getting you an array with all returned rows, which makes your query code essentially a one-liner:

```
$users = $database->query("SELECT * FROM user")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Also, it is not clear what you want to return, an array with users or just the count? If the latter, you shouldn't select records but have to ask a database to do the count. For this occasion PDO again have a method for you,

```
$count = $database->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: My code is mess, absolutely agreed because I am messing around with different solutions. Sorry if I were unclear but yes, I want to return array with users. But the solution gives me an error `"PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on null"` I've read the PHP PDO documentation also. This was the first thing I tried.

Comment: If I am using` mysql_fetch_assoc($users)`. It returns status code 200 but not returning the array with populated users.

Comment: well then, what is this Database class thing?

Answer (score 1):

why are your using 
`mysql_fetch_assoc` . 
you need to use

`$database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

```
while ($row = $database->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $users[] = $row; 
    }
```